# POST method not allowed in laravel

Tags: forms, post, laravel, methods

i want to post a form on public/config , the form is located on the same page as public/config but it shows me this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

form:

```
<form action="config" method="POST" id="tipsterform-add" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

routes:

```
Route::get('config', 'ConfigController@showIndex');
Route::post('config', 'ConfigController@storeTipster');
```

controller:

```
class ConfigController extends BaseController {

public function showIndex(){
    return View::make('config');
}

public function storeTipster(){
    return echo 'test';
}
```

}

help me!

Comment: What url do you have when getting this error? Show the full code of the form

Comment: i get this error with public/config

Comment: <form action="config" method="POST" id="tipsterform-add" class="form-horizontal" role="form"> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success center-block"/>

Comment: http://www.hurl.it/ use this to test  Send a POST to /config and if the response is the same let us know.

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application

Comment: hurl.it doesnt work on a lowal server i think